# Perl - Can't get data from metasploit RPC server

Tags: perl, rpc

What I have used as resource : https://metasploit.help.rapid7.com/v1/docs/rpc-api

First I have started msf rpc server :

```
msfrpcd -U msf -P test -f -S -a 127.0.0.1
[*] MSGRPC starting on 127.0.0.1:55553 (NO SSL):Msg...
[*] MSGRPC ready at 2019-01-11 00:56:29 +0900.
```

after that the server is up and is showing up via browser in http://127.0.0.1:55553

The script I have used while using XML::RPC to get data

```
use XML::RPC;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fm = XML::RPC->new( 'http://127.0.0.1:55553/api/' );

my $session = $fm->call( 'auth.login', { username => 'msf', password => 'test' });

my $x = $fm->call('group.command'); #api
```

The error when I run the script :

```
no data at /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1/XML/RPC.pm line 288.
```

It seems that the api used is not working or perphaps something wrong

Do you have any better way to get data from msf rpc server?

Comment: Why are you trying to use XML::RPC? Nothing in the Metasploit API documentation even mentions XML.

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/MsgPack::RPC and https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::MPRPC::Client look relevant.

Comment: melpomene , I know it uses binary/message-pack , I have seen many python scripts and attempt to translate it , cause I have found many using rpc xml module to connect to msf rpc server

Comment: and thank you about that module , it seems a handy one , i were searching for a one all the day

Comment: ... I just searched MetaCPAN for `msgpack` and `messagepack`.